# The type signature of a combinator does not match the type signature of its equivalent Lambda function

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus, combinators, type-signature, combinatory-logic

Consider this combinator:

```
S (S K)
```

Apply it to the arguments X Y:

```
S (S K) X Y
```

It contracts to:

```
X Y
```

I converted S (S K) to the corresponding Lambda terms and got this result:

```
(\x y -> x y)
```

I used the Haskell WinGHCi tool to get the type signature of (\x y -> x y) and it returned:

```
(t1 -> t) -> t1 -> t
```

That makes sense to me.

Next, I used WinGHCi to get the type signature of s (s k) and it returned:

```
((t -> t1) -> t) -> (t -> t1) -> t
```

That doesn't make sense to me. Why are the type signatures different?

Note: I defined s, k, and i as:

```
s = (\f g x -> f x (g x))
k = (\a x -> a)
i = (\f -> f)
```

Comment: The latter type is the same as the first one, just stricter. Are there any constraints on `X` and `Y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all who responded to my question. I have studied your responses. To be sure that I understand what I've learned I have written my own answer to my question. If my answer is not correct, please let me know.

We start with the types of `k` and `s`:

```
   k  :: t1 -> t2 -> t1 
   k  =  (\a x -> a) 

   s  :: (t3 -> t4 -> t5) -> (t3 -> t4) -> t3 -> t5 
   s  =  (\f g x -> f x (g x))
```

Let's first work on determing the type signature of `(s k)`.

Recall `s`'s definition:

```
s = (\f g x -> f x (g x))
```

Substituting `k` for `f` results in `(\f g x -> f x (g x))` contracting to:

```
(\g x -> k x (g x))
```

**Important** The type of g and x must be consistent with `k`'s type signature.

Recall that `k` has this type signature:

```
   k :: t1 -> t2 -> t1
```

So, for this function definition `k x (g x)` we can infer:

- The type of `x` is the type of `k`'s first argument, which is the type `t1`.
- The type of `k`'s second argument is `t2`, so the result of `(g x)` must be `t2`.
- `g` has `x` as its argument which we've already determined has type `t1`. So the type signature of `(g x)` is `(t1 -> t2)`.
- The type of `k`'s result is `t1`, so the result of `(s k)` is `t1`.

So, the type signature of `(\g x -> k x (g x))` is this:

```
   (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t1
```

Next, `k` is defined to always return its first argument. So this:

```
k x (g x)
```

contracts to this:

```
x
```

And this:

```
(\g x -> k x (g x))
```

contracts to this:

```
(\g x -> x)
```

Okay, now we have figured out `(s k)`:

```
   s k  :: (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t1 
   s k  =  (\g x -> x)
```

Now let's determine the type signature of `s (s k)`.

We proceed in the same manner.

Recall `s`'s definition:

```
s = (\f g x -> f x (g x))
```

Substituting `(s k)` for `f` results in `(\f g x -> f x (g x))` contracting to:

```
(\g x -> (s k) x (g x))
```

**Important** The type of `g` and `x` must be consistent with `(s k)`'s type signature.

Recall that `(s k)` has this type signature:

```
   s k :: (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t1
```

So, for this function definition `(s k) x (g x)` we can infer:

- The type of `x` is the type of `(s k)`'s first argument, which is the type `(t1 -> t2)`.
- The type of `(s k)`'s second argument is `t1`, so the result of `(g x)` must be `t1`.
- `g` has `x` as its argument, which we've already determined has type `(t1 -> t2)`. 
  So the type signature of `(g x)` is `((t1 -> t2) -> t1)`.
- The type of `(s k)`'s result is `t1`, so the result of `s (s k)` is `t1`.

So, the type signature of `(\g x -> (s k) x (g x))` is this:

```
   ((t1 -> t2) -> t1) -> (t1 -> t2) -> t1
```

Earlier we determined that `s k` has this definition:

```
   (\g x -> x)
```

That is, it is a function that takes two arguments and returns the second.

Therefore, this:

```
   (s k) x (g x)
```

Contracts to this:

```
   (g x)
```

And this:

```
   (\g x -> (s k) x (g x))
```

contracts to this:

```
   (\g x -> g x)
```

Okay, now we have figured out `s (s k)`.

```
   s (s k)  :: ((t1 -> t2) -> t1) -> (t1 -> t2) -> t1 
   s (s k)  =  (\g x -> g x)
```

Lastly, compare the type signature of `s (s k)` with the type signature of this function:

```
   p = (\g x -> g x)
```

The type of `p` is:

```
   p :: (t1 -> t) -> t1 -> t
```

`p` and `s (s k)` have the same definition `(\g x -> g x)` so why do they have different type signatures?

The reason that `s (s k)` has a different type signature than `p` is that there are no constraints on `p`. We saw that the `s` in `(s k)` is constrained to be consistent with the type signature of `k`, and the first `s` in `s (s k)` is constrained to be consistent with the type signature of `(s k)`. So, the type signature of `s (s k)` is constrained due to its argument. Even though `p` and `s (s k)` have the same definition the constraints on `g` and `x` differ.

Answer (score 9):

We start with the types of `k` and `s`

```
k :: t1 -> t2 -> t1
k = (\a x -> a)

s :: (t3 -> t4 -> t5) -> (t3 -> t4) -> t3 -> t5
s = (\f g x -> f x (g x))
```

So passing `k` as the first argument of `s`, we unify `k`'s type with the type of `s`'s first argument, and use `s` at the type

```
s :: (t1 -> t2 -> t1) -> (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t1
```

hence we obtain

```
s k :: (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t1
s k = (\g x -> k x (g x)) = (\g x -> x)
```

Then in `s (s k)`, the outer `s` is used at the type (`t3 = t1 -> t2`, `t4 = t5 = t1`)

```
s :: ((t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t1) -> ((t1 -> t2) -> t1) -> (t1 -> t2) -> t1
```

applying that to `s k` drops the type of the first argument and leaves us with

```
s (s k) :: ((t1 -> t2) -> t1) -> (t1 -> t2) -> t1
```

As a summary: In Haskell, the type of `s (s k)` is derived from the types of its constituent subexpressions, not from its effect on its argument(s). Therefore it has a less general type than the lambda expression that denotes the effect of `s (s k)`.

Answer (score 7):

The type system you are using is basically the same as simply-typed lambda calculus (you are not using any recursive functions or recursive types). Simply-typed lambda calculus is not fully general; it is not Turing-complete, and it cannot be used to write general recursion. SKI combinator calculus is Turing-complete, and can be used to write fixed-point combinators and general recursion; therefore, the full power of SKI combinator calculus cannot be expressed in simply-typed lambda calculus (although it can be in untyped lambda calculus).

Comment: Important to know, given the inevitable question '"ow come Haskell won't let me write 's i i`?"  But doesn't really answer the OP's question as to why the types are different.

Comment: And whoever downvoted you really ought to give a reason. Anonymous downvotes aren't nice.