# What does this combinator do: s (s k)

Tags: haskell, lambda, lambda-calculus, combinators, combinatory-logic

I now understand the type signature of `s (s k)`:

```
s (s k)  :: ((t1 -> t2) -> t1) -> (t1 -> t2) -> t1
```

And I can create examples that work without error in the Haskell WinGHCi tool:

**Example**:

```
s (s k) (\g -> 2) (\x -> 3)
```

returns `2`.

**Example**:

```
s (s k) (\g -> g 3) successor
```

returns `4`.

where `successor` is defined as so:

```
successor = (\x -> x + 1)
```

Nonetheless, I still don't have *an intuitive feel* for what `s (s k)` does.

The combinator `s (s k)` takes any two functions `f` and `g`. What does `s (s k)` do with `f` and `g`?  Would you give me *the big picture* on what `s (s k)` does please?

Comment: The defination for  `S (S K)` is missing. Is this the same `s` and `k` in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592191/the-type-signature-of-a-combinator-does-not-match-the-type-signature-of-its-equi ?

Comment: Btw, what is intuitive? Do you found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros intuitive? Can you imagine a snake eats itself and vanish? Or a robot that builds itself from itself? You need better sense on something acting on itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alright, let's look at what `S (S K)` means. I'm going to use these definitions:

```
S = \x y z -> x z (y z)
K = \x y   -> x

S (S K) = (\x y z -> x z (y z)) ((\x y z -> x z (y z)) (\a b -> a)) -- rename bound variables in K
        = (\x y z -> x z (y z)) (\y z -> (\a b -> a) z (y z)) -- apply S to K
        = (\x y z -> x z (y z)) (\y z -> (\b -> z) (y z)) -- apply K to z
        = (\x y z -> x z (y z)) (\y z -> z) -- apply (\_ -> z) to (y z)
        = (\x y z -> x z (y z)) (\a b -> b) -- rename bound variables
        = (\y z -> (\a b -> b) z (y z)) -- apply S to (\a b -> b)
        = (\y z -> (\b -> b) (y z)) -- apply (\a b -> b) to z
        = (\y z -> y z) -- apply id to (y z)
```

As you can see, it's just `($)` with more specific type.

Comment: Another way to see this: the type is `((t1 -> t2) -> t1) -> (t1 -> t2) -> t1`.  Adding parentheses, we get `((t1 -> t2) -> t1) -> ((t1 -> t2) -> t1)`.  Letting the type `α` stand for `(t1 -> t2) -> t1`, this is just `α -> α`, and so, by parametricity, `s (s k)` is the identity function with a more specific type.  (And of course, `($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b` is *also* just the identity function with a more specific type.)

Comment: Indeed, if we η-reduce `\y -> \z -> y z`, we get `\y -> y`.

Comment: In combinators, S K y z = K z (y z) = z. Then S (S K) y z = S K z (y z) = K (y z) (z (y z)) = y z.

Comment: @AntalS-Z, it's a bit cheeky to appeal to parametricity on a type you generalised yourself :P it's true that the type here pretty much demands that the function is a type-restricted identity, but e.g. `(a -> a) -> (a -> a)` is another type that is `α -> α` for some `α`, yet has plenty of non-identity values.

Comment: @benmachine: This is what I get for playing fast and loose with free theorems.  Duly noted :-)